# NoMethodError ; private or undefined method?

Tags: ruby, methods

```
class Array
  def my_uniq(array_taken)
    new_array=[]
    array_taken.each do |element|
      new_array << element unless arr.include(element)
    end
  end
end
Array.my_uniq([1,2,3,3])
```

I am using ruby calc1.rb in terminal to call the program. Terminal is in the correct folder and the file is saved in the correct folder.

Output

```
calc1.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined method `my_uniq' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

It appears previous answers were about either calling the method before it was defined or look, to me, like my solution that calls the class, then invokes the method on an array. Is there a private or undefined method going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the method as a class method to work. But you created the method as an instance method of the class `Array` and  calling on the `Array` class object, not on the instance of the `Array`, thus you got the error.

Below will work :

```
class Array
  def self.my_uniq(array_taken)
    new_array=[]
    array_taken.each do |element|
      new_array << element unless new_array.include(element)
    end
    new_array
  end
end
Array.my_uniq([1,2,3,3])
```

Looking also at the error, it seems, you called the method `my_uniq` from top level. But in that case also, it wouldn't work, as on toplevel `self` is `main`, instance of `Object` class.But the method is not defined inside the `Object` class as an instance method, so bare method call from toplevel also wouldn't work.

Comment: You know this code will not work still, right? `arr` is not defined, `new_array` is not returned...

Comment: @UriAgassi Thanks.. Don't know, what to say about `arr`.. As it is confusing. The OP knows, only the context. If you have any idea, tell me, I will put it there..

Comment: @UriAgassi Yes.. It is. Thanks for making the answer more perfect. I didn't notice the logic, only *why not working part*... :-)

Comment: Thanks man. From what I understand, the object names weren't consistent throughout the definition. I need to perform an operation on self to change it to my function definition, and I need to call the output new_array within the definition.

Thanks again.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I got it to work. See the comments below for the code I tested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script that I got it to work with in case anyone is wondering

```
class Array
def self.my_uniq (array_taken)
    new_array=[]
    array_taken.each do |element|
      new_array << element unless new_array.include?(element)
    end
    new_array
  end
end
p Array.my_uniq([1,2,3,3,3])
```